# ResourceDictionary doesn't load because of overriding OnStartup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, overriding

I'm doing wpf project using MVVM. 
I am using override OnStartup at the App.xaml.cs file because I'm using NavigationService clas in order to navigate between pages. 
The problem is that the ResourceDictionary found at App.xaml file  is not loaded, therefore I can't use the Locator. here's my code -

App.xaml file:

```
<Application x:Class="TalkBackClient2.App" 

         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace"  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" d1p1:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
<Application.Resources>

<ResourceDictionary>

        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TalkBackClient2.ViewModel" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

App.xaml.cs file:

```
    public partial class App : Application
{
    Navigation.NavigationService nav;
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
 nav = new Navigation.NavigationService();
    }
}
```

NavigationService file:

```
namespace TalkBackClient2.Navigation
{
class NavigationService
{
    #region fields
    private const WindowsEnum FirstScreen = WindowsEnum.LoginScreen;
    private MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    private LoginScreen loginScreen = new LoginScreen();
    private RegistrationScreen registrationScreen = new RegistrationScreen();
    private ChatScreen chatViewModel = new ChatScreen();
    private GameScreen gameScreen = new GameScreen();

    #endregion

    public NavigationService()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<NavMessage>(this, navToPage);
        openWindow(FirstScreen);
    }

    private void navToPage(NavMessage navMessage)
    {
        if (navMessage.NavFrom != WindowsEnum.MainWindow)
        {
            CloseWindow(navMessage.NavFrom);
        }

        openWindow(navMessage.NavToPage);
    }

    private void CloseWindow(WindowsEnum navFrom)
    {
        switch (navFrom)
        {
            case WindowsEnum.LoginScreen:
                loginScreen.Hide();
                break;
            case WindowsEnum.GameScreen:
                gameScreen.Hide();
                break;
            case WindowsEnum.RegistrationScreen:
                registrationScreen.Hide();
                break;
            case WindowsEnum.ChatScreen:
                chatViewModel.Hide();
                break;
            case WindowsEnum.MainWindow:
                mainWindow.Hide();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void openWindow(WindowsEnum navTo)
    {
        switch (navTo)
        {

            case WindowsEnum.RegistrationScreen:
                if (registrationScreen == null)
                {
                    registrationScreen = new RegistrationScreen();
                }
                registrationScreen.Show();
                break;
            case WindowsEnum.GameScreen:
                if (gameScreen == null)
                {
                    gameScreen = new GameScreen();
                }
                gameScreen.Show();
                break;

            case WindowsEnum.ChatScreen:
                if (chatViewModel == null)
                {
                    chatViewModel = new ChatScreen();
                }
                chatViewModel.Show();
                break;
            case WindowsEnum.MainWindow:
                    mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                var dataContext =   (MainWindowViewModel)mainWindow.DataContext;
                dataContext.Greeting = $"Greeting         {Util.LoggedInUser.UserName}";
                   mainWindow.Show();
                break;
            case WindowsEnum.LoginScreen:
            default:
                if (loginScreen == null)
                {
                    loginScreen = new LoginScreen();
                }
                loginScreen.Show();
                break;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As proposed in [fdub's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44637360/6926836) use merged dictionaries in `App.xaml`.
The important thing here is that it is only possible to link to separate resource `.xaml` files with the `Source` attribute. Inline resource definition are not possible here.

See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries?view=net-5.0) for `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries`

Example:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/> 
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to define your namespace xmlns:vm in the app tag instead of in your viewModel Tag?

Comment: do you mean to write <app :ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TalkBackClient2.ViewModel" />  ? 
If so, there is no app  tag as I can see..

Comment: nop i meean `<application xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TalkBackClient.ViewModel>` then in the resources you use your tag `<vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="locator"/>`

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I get a  run-time error - "Cannot find resource named 'locator'. Resource names are case sensitive." although it clearly have that resourse(intellisense  recognized it).
I think that confirm it that the override OnStartup happendes before the resources being loaded

Answer (score 0):

I was just puzzled by the same problem. After playing around a little (using .NET 4.5.2), there seem to be two possible solutions (and those puzzle me even more as I haven't yet found out the backgrounds as to why they work).

**First solution**: Handle the Startup event instead of overriding OnStartup.
Obviously when opening a window within the event handler, the ResourceDictionary gets loaded before and is available to your window.

**Second solution** (I'm really curious for an explanation): Put your resources inside a ResourceDictionary which is a merged ResourceDictionary of your App resources. In this case even if overriding OnStartup, the resources within the merged ResourceDictionary are available to your windows.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                [... your resource here ...]
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Maybe anyone can provide further details on the startup mechanism of WPF applications that can clear this up.